# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Tags: android, google-play-services

### I am trying to link google play services to my project that i had preveously developed a month ago.

***So i followed the below steps:***

- I imported playservices library to workspace (i ticked the copy
  option)
- right clicked on project, android add library, i selected play
  services and clicked apply and ok

***What is happening***

- I am not able to link the services lib even after doing above steps
- I get the error as `No resource found that matches the given name (at
  'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').`

When i check the proj-lib --- even after linking the playservices i can see libraries are not linked properly

[image]

---

### How can i resolve this !!

***I even cleaned workspace and restarted it .... updated playservices version ....still no effect***

Comment: Try to Use Android-Studio

Comment: I have developed the old proj with eclipse !

Answer (score 0):

```
<application... >

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 ...
 </application>
```

add above to your application manifest.

Comment: I already have it in manifest ! and it is working fine in my office machine .... in my home when i try to setup with my playservies i am having this problem